# RSA the difficulty in getting private key at very first place

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I've just learnt about RSA, there's one concept I find very confusing. The reason RSA is very secure is that given public keys {e, n} , it's very hard for people to calculate the private keys {d, n}. But isn't it the same situation when they get the private keys at the first place, since it's so difficult, why is Alice able to calculate the private key and tell Bob?

Comment: The great thing about RSA key pairs is that you can distribute the public key without ever having to send the private key to anybody.  I hope that maybe helps you think about them.

Comment: @DanFarrell But I don't understand this: when you already have public key {e,n}and want to generate private key, you need to solve for private key {d,n} given d⋅e ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)). This calculation is hard isn't it?

Comment: Incredibly hard.  You "can't" generate a private key from a public key - only the reverse.  That's the whole point :)

Comment: @DanFarrell Hey Dan, I think I found the trick! pq= n, Alice knows not only n but also p and q, thus she can calculate   φ(n) = (p-1)(q-1) super easily; while the third guy who only knows n can hardly calculate φ(n) without knowing p and q. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure if your math works out, but you've got the right idea.  Alice knows all she needs to calculate.  Though somehow she can also calculate different public keys - not sure how that works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography, without involving programming.

Comment: Arch1tect: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it's very hard to calculate ax + by = 1 but it's simply log(n) complexity. 
And the hard part is actually calculating  φ(n) because they don't know n = pq! Alice knows p and q, that's why it's much much simpler for her. 
Problem solved, thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that Alice *chooses* a private key, then tells Bob her *public* key. Bob can only use the key to encrypt, and it's very hard to get the private key *based on the public key*. If you are picking (or creating) a new private key out of thin air, that's easy; all you have to do is pick a couple prime numbers that satisfy a few requirements. It's calculating the private key *based on the public key* that is (and needs to be) difficult. [RSA wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29)

Comment: OK, here is what I find confusing specifically: " Alice chooses a private key, then tells Bob her public key." Alice choose a private key out of thin out of thin air{e,n}, true, that's easy, but she has to calculate and find the public key{d,n} herself right? Using de=1 mod n

Comment: The public key matching a given private key can be calculated fairly easily - really easily if you let a program calculate it for you.  In fact you can generate multiple public keys that match a given private key, if you like.  Since I'm into open source software, I use `ssh-keygen` for this kind of thing.